# How to change ownership of hiddenfiles

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I've had to move from one user to another, I have found online how to move all files (including hidden) from the old user to the new and change the ownership of those files. However how can I change the ownership of all **hidden** folders & files which I moved across to my new home dictionary in one simple command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd ~
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .*
```

- The -R will do all dirs and files in dirs.
- The . will alter only hidden files (since those always start with a .).
- The $USER needs no changing: it will be substituted to your username.

Comment: the one thing about this approach is that it changes ownership of .. (parent folder) which is often times an unintended effect of `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R user /yourdir
```

will change the owner of /yourdir and subfiles to "user".

Answer (score 0):

Using for-loop with `ls -A` option, we can find all hidden files and directory exclude `.` and `..` and then change the ownership for all hidden files and directory.

```
for i in ls -A | grep "^\.";do chown -R user:group $i;done
```

Use `xargs` option with `ls -A`

```
ls -A | grep "^\."| xargs chown user:group
```

For More details [Click Here and Visit this site](http://automationranjeet.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-change-ownership-of-hiddenfiles.html)